# Only import part of file with Browserify

Tags: javascript, babeljs, browserify

I am using Browserify to transpile ES6 to ES5 and am not happy with how Browserify includes the **entire contents** of an imported file when all I requested was a single method from that file. Simple example:

**File1.js**

```
export const firstThing = () => { console.log('I do nothing'); };
export const secondThing = () => { console.log('I do nothing as well'); };
```

**File2.js**

```
import { firstThing } from '/File1';

firstThing();
```

**File2.js After Transpilation to ES5**

```
var firstThing = function firstThing(){
    console.log('I do nothing');
};

var secondThing = function secondThing(){
    console.log('I do nothing as well');
};

firstThing();
```

Notice how Browserify is dumping the entire contents of `File1.js` into `File2.js` even though I only imported a single method from that file. This may not make much difference in small files but makes a huge difference across an entire codebase (tons of unnecessary code bloating the file size).

Relevant Browserify Code from my Gulp file:

```
browserify(file)
  .transform(babelify, {
    presets: ['env'],
  })
  .bundle((err, res) => {
    if (err) return next(chalk.red(err));
    file.contents = res;
    return next(null, file);
  });
```

Is there a way to prevent code not specifically imported into a file from being included during transpilation by Browserify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Browserify's job to do this. Importing a single function from a file still loads the whole file. You could consider running something after browserify to look for code that is unused and strip it out afterward though. For instance UglifyJS has options for removing dead code.